# Does inclusion of categorical dummy variables impact OLS prediction?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, categorical-encoding

Say I am trying to predict city price levels of apartments and my dataset contains a variable coded as 'region' (which is a larger geographical variable than city) for 4 levels: region N, region S, region W, and region E.

If my ultimate goal is prediction of city price levels of apartments using OLS, should I be including dummy variables in my regression for all n-1 regions (ie, 3 regions with 1 dropped due to multicollinearity) or just for, say, two regions that are known to be radically different than the rest, one is extremely expensive the other extremely cheap. On what basis could I make on whether to include 2 region dummies rather than all n-1 regions? I guess that the decision on how many regions to include would depend on how many regions I would to lump together as 'base'.

More importantly, underlying my question, is whether inclusion of categorical variables impact OLS prediction. I understand that for inferences purposes, I could include n-1 regions to see see what and how a region dummy is associated with city price levels, given all the other variables in the model. However, in my case, my goal is prediction.

Answer (score 0):

More dummy variables carry more information, i.e. if you only include North, the information available is now only whether an apartment is in the North part or not. If you include three dummy variables, you can fully identify which part is the apartment located. "Lumping" together regions as "base" are not a central point.

If North is extremely more expensive than East, South, and West, then having only one dummy is better than three, especially if East, South, and West have similar prices anyway (not worth two extra parameters to estimate).

But as always, the actual result may depend on your actual particular case.